# How would you go about putting a Huyabusa engine in a Deawoo Matiz?

Tags: small-engine, custom

My first car was a Deawoo Matiz. I have a real fondness for the little car and always thought if it just had a bit more power it would be great. My question is how would you go about doing this? You would probably have to build the car up from  scratch. You probably only keeping the shell and upgrading virtually everything else. I have seen minis with these engines, so I don't think it is impossible.

I would strip out the back seats and have a mini van type of effect in the back. I would also like a bit of gentleman's wood in the dash (like old jags). I would put two bucket seats and a killer sound system. Twin exhausts like a M3. It would be painted matte black with green flame decals on the sides.

If I do one day do this I would just like to go to the autoshop and not sound like a total dork. So what kind of upgrades would this car exactly need for such a engine.

Comment: There's not a lot going for that car when it comes to a bigger engine TBH, very little room under the hood, no kits to speak of, it would be very custom. Try tweaking the existing engine for more power first, but keep in mind that car looks awfully top-heavy, you may not want it to go that fast!

Comment: Of course something like this can be done and it possibly may have been done already.  But at its very best it's going to be something that takes significant skills in fabrication.  Based on the tone of your question, I can't imagine that you're going to be able to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by a "bit more power" - another 20bhp may be sufficient and can be done with little changes. But add 120bhp then the consequences are much more serious...

So, suspension upgrades, tires, powertrain ie gearbox, driveshafts and obviously brakes.

Asking a shop to do this for you would be **very** expensive...

But doing it yourself would mean learning lots of skills and having the tools needed...